# how to access ipad or iphone through bluetooth mouse?

Tags: iphone

I am impementing one iphone and ipad applcation in which i want to implement below functionality.

Using this application ipad or iphone will connect with bluetooth mouse.

After  connecting this mouse user can operate ipad or iphone through mouse.

I dont know is it possible or not.
I have done lots of googling but not success.

Please give me advice for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's operating system and user interface for the iPhone / iPad don't support using a mouse at all – as in, there's no such thing as a cursor, much less support for connecting to an external pointing device.

Comment: I have seen below link: http://www.intomobile.com/2010/05/09/ipad-bluetooth-keyboard-bluetooth-mouse-desktop-ipad-computer/ in this video cursor is display....so is it possible from developer side

Comment: That video was taken on a jailbroken iPad. If you jailbreak your iPad then you can install third-party patches and drivers, including drivers for a Bluetooth mouse – but an app that relies on those drivers will only work on jailbroken devices, and won't be accepted into Apple's App Store.

Comment: Ya I know that.... Suppose I will implement for jailbreak ipad then its possible right? Then can you give me advice for that